# Visual Studio Extension To Get Developer Input

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-extensions

I'm new on developing vs extensions and I wanted to write a simple extension that can be called in Visual Studio IDE by a shortcut key and shows a form with some textboxes and an add button in it, after clicking the button the form closes and those texts on textboxes get inserted into the code.

it'll be very good if you can show me an example on how to this.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The feature you'd like to achieve is similar to this feature: [Walkthrough: Implementing Code Snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926100.aspx). You can refer to this link for how to show dialog from code editor and insert code into it. And then customize the code and UI according to your requirement.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need to show an input form to developer and get him or her comment from that input form.